# Why does TWebBrowser on iOS stop loading local file after about 12 cycles?

Tags: ios, c++builder

I am trying to view a file I have downloaded (in one of several formats, but most often .pdf) on iOS.  I tried saving it to a local file and then Navigating a TWebBrowser component to the saved file.  It works for a number of times per program run, but then the file stops opening into the TWebBrowser until I restart the program.

I tried creating a new TWebBrowser with each cycle, which sometimes succeeds a little longer, but eventually the file stops opening until the program is restarted.

To reproduce this using RAD Studio XE6 Update 1:  Create a new iOS C++ Application, and put a TButton and TWebBrowser on the form.  Add `#include "System.IOUtils.hpp"`
 to the top of Unit1.cpp.  Double-click the TButton, and in the OnClick handler, use this code:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender) {
    static int ctr = 1;
    String fileName = System::Ioutils::TPath::GetDocumentsPath() +
        System::Sysutils::PathDelim + String(ctr) + ".html";

    TStringStream* stream =
        new TStringStream("This is document number " + String(ctr) + ", " +
        fileName);
    TFileStream *output = new TFileStream(fileName, fmCreate);
    output->CopyFrom(stream, 0);
    delete output; // save the file to storage

    WebBrowser1->Navigate("file://" + fileName);
    ShowMessage("Just displayed file " + fileName);
    ctr++;

}
```

Build, deploy, and launch on iPad running iOS 7.1  Click the button, and the file is created, saved, and opened in the TWebBrowser.  Keep clicking the button.  After about 12-20 clicks, the file stops opening in the TWebBrowser.  When that happens, the previous file content remains visible in the TWebBrowser (the program increments the integer in the filename, and shows a message with the filename, so it is easy to notice).  Nothing but restarting the program will get it working again.

Here is the code for creating a new TWebBrowser on each click (also define `TWebBrowser* OldWebBrowser_` in Unit1.h file, and set `OldWebBrowser_ = NULL` in the form constructor):

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender) {
    static int ctr = 1;
    String fileName = System::Ioutils::TPath::GetDocumentsPath() +
        System::Sysutils::PathDelim + String(ctr) + ".html";

    TStringStream* stream =
        new TStringStream("This is document number " + String(ctr) + ", " +
        fileName);
    TFileStream *output = new TFileStream(fileName, fmCreate);
    output->CopyFrom(stream, 0);
    delete output; // save the file to storage

    if (OldWebBrowser_) {
        delete OldWebBrowser_;
        OldWebBrowser_ = NULL;
    }
    TWebBrowser* WebBrowser1 = new TWebBrowser(NULL);
    OldWebBrowser_ = WebBrowser1;
    WebBrowser1->Parent = this;
    WebBrowser1->Height = Height / 2;
    WebBrowser1->Width = Width * 0.9;
    WebBrowser1->Position->Y = Height / 5;
    WebBrowser1->Position->X = Width / 20;

    WebBrowser1->Navigate("file://" + fileName);
    ShowMessage("Just displayed file " + fileName);
    ctr++;

}
```

With this technique, it takes about 16 cycles for the TWebBrowser to stop loading the file, but eventually it happens.  When it happens here, the TWebBrowser is created, but remains blank, and does not load the saved file.  Only restarting the program will get it working again.

This does not happen with TWebBrowser on Android, which keeps opening the new file with every button click.

How can I keep the TWebBrowser opening my saved files?

Answer (score 0):

The method `Navigate` might throw exceptions, so you'd better wrap your code into a try/catch block. I highly doubt some exception was thrown without your attention.

It is really wired. Here are some thoughts on troubleshooting:

1. Test the app on Windows platform?
2. Navigate current page to blank first and then navigate to another local HTML.
3. Slow down button click (If you click `TForm1::Button1Click` to frequently.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  The TWebBrowser is a mobile component, and not available on Windows, according to the docs.  When I run this program on Windows, it builds and runs, but the TWebBrowser is not visible.  Navigate("about:blank") does not do anything (does not clear the TWebBrowser), and calling that before each Navigate() doesn't work.  I don't know what you mean about "slow down button click".  I wanted to simplify this to reproduce, so no try/catch, but adding try/catch doesn't help.  I am running a Debug build in the IDE, but the same thing happens in Release build.

Comment: @nachbar I worked with the traditional Windows variant, which is a wrapper of MSIE. But the one you are using is a wrapper of Webkit. As it works on Android but failed on iOS, I do not have any idea about that. Anyway (1) observe the memory usage. Maybe iOS has some restriction on memory per app (2) free and recreate browser instance will not help.